# Canvas view with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I am looking for something like

http://www.art.com/products/p10300303-sa-i809278/joan-miro-bleu-ii.htm?sorig=cat&sorigid=0&dimvals=24099&ui=a06af6d911c64e728faeee7c8a861b2e

On the page, please click view in room(at the bottom right of the pic). It will show how the picture will look when applied to a room (basically super imposes the picture on a wall in the room). art.com has made it with flash. I am looking for how to do this in HTML5/javascript. Any pointers are welcome !!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly simple.

You'd add the background or "room" image as a static image in the background, and add the picture as another element which is draggable. Finally, you'd add another element as a container for the draggable, which would be the area on the background photo you want the the user to be able to drag the picture around.

See http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

```
<img id="background" src="backgroundImage.png" />
<div id="bounds"></div>
<div id="draggableImage">
  <img id="picture" src="picture.png" />
</div>
```

and then

```
$('#draggableImage').draggable({
  'containment' : $('#bounds').eq();
});
```

Use CSS to shape the "bounds" element to be where you want the picture to be dragged to (for example, you don't want to drag the picture onto the floor).